# Need to Join 3 Tables with a complex conditon

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 3 Data Extensions (Data Tables)

```
Subscription

CustomerInfo

Survey
```

All three tables have CustomerId as field.

Below is my Criteria:

> 1. Check for B13 or B26 in Benfitids of Subscripton
> 2. EmailOptin is True in CustomerInfo
> 3. CreateDt in Subscription should be over 30 days and
> 4. they are in Survey Table with the following conditions:
>
> QuestionId= ‘purchaseIntentQuestion’ and AnswerId = '3'
>       OR
>       QuestionId='goldenQuestion' AND (AnswerId = '1' OR AnswerId = '2')

Make sure that you have no duplicate records for Customerids

I wrote the below query but it is not returning results as expected. Pls advise

```
SELECT distinct sub.CustomerId, Cus.EmailOptin, srv.QuestionID,srv.AnswerId
FROM [Subscription] sub
JOIN [Survey Questions] srv ON sub.CustomerId = srv.CustomerId
JOIN [CustomerInfo] cus ON sub.CustomerId = cus.CustomerId
WHERE 1 = 1
AND CAST(sub.CreateDt AS DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() -30 AS DATE)
AND Cus.EmailOptin  = 'True'
AND 
(
sub.BenefitIds LIKE '%B13%'
OR
sub.BenefitIds LIKE '%B26%'
)
AND 
(
(srv.QuestionId = 'purchaseIntentQuestion' AND srv.AnswerId = '3')
OR 
(srv.QuestionId = 'goldenQuestion' AND (srv.AnswerId = '1' OR srv.AnswerId = '2' ))
)
```

For the above query even EmailOptin is not coming as True.
Pls advise.

Comment: What is 1 = 1 ?

Comment: @JimMacaulay - It is just to differentiate all conditions that are present in the query.
Serves no other purpose.

Comment: Then removing it will be better. Can you post the error you are getting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said "it is not returning results as expected" so I didn't really knew what needs to be fixed. I have a feeling that `CAST(GETDATE() -30 AS DATE)` was the issue . I also replaced `OR` with `IN()` for readability. Try this:

```
SELECT distinct sub.CustomerId,
                Cus.EmailOptin,
                srv.QuestionID,
                srv.AnswerId
  FROM [ Subscription ] sub
  JOIN [ Survey Questions ] srv
    ON sub.CustomerId = srv.CustomerId
  JOIN [ CustomerInfo ] cus
    ON sub.CustomerId = cus.CustomerId
 WHERE 1 = 1
   AND CAST(sub.CreateDt AS DATE) < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
   AND Cus.EmailOptin = 'True'
   AND (sub.BenefitIds = '%B13%' OR sub.BenefitIds LIKE '%B26%')
   AND ((srv.QuestionId = 'purchaseIntentQuestion' AND srv.AnswerId = '3') OR
       (srv.QuestionId = 'goldenQuestion' AND
       srv.AnswerId IN('1','2')))
```

Comment: I am trying it out. Meanwhile, can u pls advise what if i want to show all fields of subscribers table but still customerid shud be unique.
Will it go like 

SELECT distinct sub.*, Cus.EmailOptin, srv.QuestionID,srv.AnswerId
FROM [Subscription] sub

Comment: But if there are more then 1 record for each customerid , which of the values for all the other columns should be presented ? @PankajGupta

Comment: just mean that for eacu customerid, the combination record should be unique.

Comment: Oh, yea, then `DISTINCT` at the beggining of the select will make sure the entire column set are unique. Your other option is to use `GROUP BY col1,col2...colN` . @PankajGupta